# Add inline box-shadow option without overriding existing property

Tags: css

I have a box-shadow property applied to `.foo` in my style-sheet:

```
.foo {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 2px 0 #3C3C3C inset;
}
```

Now I want to add another option to several divs inline with different dynamically generated values without overriding the existing `box-shadow` property:

```
<div class="foo" style="box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 red inset">
</div>
<div class="foo" style="box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 blue inset">
</div>
<div class="foo" style="box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 green inset">
</div>
```

The result for the first div should look like this:

```
box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 red inset, 
  0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 
  0 0 2px 0 #3C3C3C inset
```

How could I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: take the previous value, add a new one to it, append it back to boxshadow property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your *inline* style a new rule will simply overwrite the old rule. The only way I can think of doing it with only CSS is using an absolutely positioned [pseudo element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content), although that also relies on your `.foo` being relatively positioned.

**CSS**

```
.foo:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 2px 0 #3C3C3C inset
}

.foo {
    position:relative;
    width:100px; /* added for demo */
    height:100px; /* added for demo */
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/udBVQ/)

Comment: Works nicely, thank you. Am I wrong for wanting to do this in CSS only? Or should I go with jQuery as gaynorvader suggested?

Comment: Entirely depends on your requirements. A cross-browser CSS solution _could_ be more lines of CSS as (later versions of) jQuery can take care of the different browser vendor prefixes (`-webkit-`, -moz-` for example). It of course also depends on if you already also have jQuery. I would definitely not import jQuery just for this functionality. Personally I like native CSS solutions as they should always be quicker to render.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in jQuery should work:

```
var currentBoxShadow = $('.foo').css("box-shadow");
$('.foo').css("box-shadow", "0 -5px 0 0 #FFF, " + currentBoxShadow);
currentBoxShadow = $('.bar').css("box-shadow");
$('.bar').css("box-shadow", "0 -5px 0 0 #FFF, " + currentBoxShadow);
```

If you want them all the same class, the nth-child selector could help:

```
var currentBoxShadow = $('.foo:nth-child(2)').css("box-shadow");
$('.foo:nth-child(2)').css("box-shadow", "0 -5px 0 0 #F00, " + currentBoxShadow);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want this applied to several divs, each with a different value. This wouldn't work then, would it?

Comment: If you have different selectors for those divs it should, I'll update my answer to show a second div.